# Combine list and object in terraform

Tags: terraform

How do I combine something like

```
[for x in var.variable : { "key" : x , "value" : true}]
```

and

```
{ "key" : "*", "value" : true}
```

Say `var.variable` is an array/list with values [1,2]

and then I need to perform a jsonencode on the above result in terraform.

I have tried merge, join, concat but somehow nothing seems to work or maybe I dont know how to use them correctly.

I need the final output something like -

```
[
   {
     "key" : 1,
     "value" : true

   },
{
     "key" : 2,
     "value" : true

   },
{
     "key" : "*",
     "value" : true

   },
]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248006/discussion-between-prakhar-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
variable "variable" {
  default = [1,2]
}

output "test" {
  value = jsonencode(concat(
            [for x in var.variable : { "key" : x , "value" : true}], 
            [{ "key" : "*", "value" : true}])) 
}
```